# Postgres: "show max_connections;" output a different value from postgresql.conf file

Tags: postgresql, max-connections

I'm trying to increase the max_connections value from the config file, but the `show max_connections;` command always shows 100.

I restarted postgres after changing the conf file,

I have modified the correct config file which is displayed by the command: `show config_file;`

Comment: You can use `select setting, source, sourcefile, sourceline from pg_settings where name = 'max_connections';` to check where the current value is coming from.

Comment: I find that it uses "postgresql.auto.conf" instead of "postgresql.conf", How to change the sourcefile to "postgresql.conf" please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the current value is stored in `postgresql.auto.conf`, it was changed using [`ALTER SYSTEM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersystem.html) and thus has priority over any value in `postgresql.conf`.

You can either use `ALTER SYSTEM` again to increase the value:

```
alter system set max_connections = 250;
```

which will adjust the value stored in `postgresql.auto.conf`

Or you can remove the entry from `postgresql.auto.conf` by using:

```
alter system reset max_connections;
```

Then the value from `postgresql.conf` will be used.

In either case, you have to restart Postgres to apply the new value.